# JQuery Click Function, Jquery Toggle Issue

Tags: jquery, click, slidetoggle, submenu

```
jQuery('.query-links ul').click(function() {

    if (jQuery('.child-posts').length == 1) {
        jQuery('.child-posts').slideToggle(200);
    }

    else {
        jQuery('.child-posts.opened').slideToggle(200).removeClass('opened');
        jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('.child-posts').slideToggle(200).addClass('opened');
    }

    return false; 
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cDz7/8/)

I have this JQuery code that is running a sidebar menu, and everything is working good except that when the sub-menu is open if it's clicked it doesn't close, it opens again. I would like the menu to close if it's clicked when it's open. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. - Jason

Update: the first part of the code deals with an instance of the menu only having one .child-posts DIV. The Menus are different based on the POSTS attached to their respective categories. (Wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target current `.childpost` under your clicked `ul`:

```
if (jQuery(this).find('.child-posts').length == 1) {
    jQuery(this).find('.child-posts').slideToggle(200);
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cDz7/6/)**

---

Edit: You can shorten your code to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.query-links ul').click(function() {
        var childPost = $(this).find('.child-posts');
        $('.child-posts').not(childPost).slideUp().removeClass('opened'); 
        childPost.addClass('opened').slideToggle();
    }); 
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cDz7/12/)**

Comment: My Fiddle was off, please check the Update, and the new Fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: Also the other menu closing functionality isn't working now, how is that working?